# Django Social Registration with google button

Tags: python, django, authentication, social-media

I have been using:

> {% openid_form 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
>   'https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-32.png' %}

in order to facilitate google login/OAUTH, and everything seems to be working smoothly, except as you can see I have had to use a static G+ image in order to link to the actual authentication instead of a proper google sign in button..

this is what is used in the docs:

```
{% openid_form 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id' 'login/with/google.png' %}
```

but obviously I have no login/with/google.png on my server...so is there some common sense thing I am supposed to be using to get a proper google sign in button?

Thanks, and sorry for being so naive with the library

Comment: Do you get any console log errors in either the browser, or django runserver console? One way is, Just download the link in [g+](https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-32.png) locally, and link `openid_form` from there

Comment: sorry, that image is just a random image I've been using as a placeholder, I am looking for a way to get the actual (I'm guessing there is one..) google sign in widget. (I have no errors, just trying to get the correct widget to display)

Comment: Something like [this](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdrMO36yiavHqpLsD2-hnURpeZdIejqY0NYMgU2QJPNUxj5sY2Ng) ?

Comment: yes, but I'm Imagining that it would be more than just the image, but perhaps I would need to code that myself. i.e. where once signed in it says hello user next to the G+ like on other sites. Otherwise I suppose I would just scale that image down and use it..wanted a much cleaner solution than that though.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, [openID](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/) is not [OAuth](http://oauth.net/). From the link you are using to google, you are using openID.

Second, from what I've understood, you are trying to apply the correct image to your button.

Well, there is no such thing as a correct image... You can use any image you want. For instance, stackoverflow uses the top part of [this image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/openid/openid-logos.png)...

In your case, you can put this image in your [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/), and use e.g. CSS to populate your html element, or see how `openid_form` is implemented to receive the image you have in your static.

In regard to the implementation of the actual login, you have to code yourself or use any available package for that ([django-openid-auth](https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth), [django-social-registration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration)).